# Commit in a loop

Tags: oracle

```
declare
type array is table of src%rowtype index by binary_integer;
l_data array ;

begin

loop

  begin
      select * bulk collect into l_data
        from src
       where processed = 'N'
         and rownum < 10
         for update of processed;
      exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
  exception
       when no_data_found then exit;
  end;

for i in 1 .. l_data.count
    loop
        update tgt set x = l_data(i).x , y = l_data(i).y where rowid = l_data(i).tgt_row_id  ;
        update src set processed = 'Y' where tgt_row_id = l_data(i).tgt_row_id;
    end loop;

commit; 



end loop;

end;
/
```

I editied the code to use bulk collect but it simply hangs in 11.2.

```
SQL> select * from src;

         X Y          TGT_ROW_ID         P
---------- ---------- ------------------ -
         1 ABC        AAAWZDAAEAAAA1EAAA Y
         1 DEF        AAAWZDAAEAAAA1EAAA Y
         2 ABC        AAAWZDAAEAAAA1EAAC Y

SQL> select * from tgt;

         X Y
---------- ----------
         1 ABC
         1
         2 ABC
```

Comment: Sorry i am not sure i am unable to format this

Comment: @Lisa I've edited your question. Just so you know, to format code all you need to do is select the text press the `{}` button

Comment: Your problem ist that l_data is an `array of src%rowtype` not `src%rowtype`. Thus you cannot select into it from the table. Use another variable for that.

Comment: Thanks Zeiss for spotting that

Comment: Storing a rowid from another (or any) table sounds like a bad idea, and the rowid for a particular row isn't necessarily immutable; why aren't you using a foreign key into the `tgt` table?

Comment: You should consider using FORALL rather than a simple FOR loop for the updates.  Bulk processing is all about improving performance, but you'll get little benefit if you still perform single row updates.  And even better (if feasible) would be just 2 simple update statements with no cursors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really several questions here.

1) The error on line 10.  That is because you need to use BULK COLLECT to select into an array:

```
select x,y,tgt_row_id 
bulk collect into l_data
from src
```

However, since l_data is defined using `src%rowtype` the above only works if the table has just the 3 columns x,y,tgt_row_id.  When using`%rowtype` it is actually **better** to use `select *` as it is sure to match the record structure.

2) Your loop never exits.  You need to add something like this:

```
loop
  select * bulk collect into l_data
    from src
   where processed = 'N'
     and rownum < 10
     for update of processed;

   exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
   ...
end loop;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the code does not come to sql prompt on oracle version 11.2.0.1

Comment: Your code hangs because you have a loop with no exit, so it runs forever if there are no errors!  You did have an exception handler with NO_DATA_FOUND, but that doesn't work with BULK COLLECT.

Comment: To make it exit when there are no matching rows, you can, immediately after the select, do `exit when sql%rowcount = 0`. But if you do match any rows to start with (`processed = 'N'`) then it'll still loop forever as you don't actually update to `'Y'`. Every time round the loop the query will get the same unprocessed rows. You have to do something with the data you're selecting.